# Microsoft Word "configures" before opening

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word-2010

I recently installed Microsoft Office (Home and Student) 2010 on my computer (Windows 8.1).

For some unknown reason, when I try to open Word, my computer starts "configuring" Word (see pic below).
This can either end with spending a short amount of time waiting for the "configuration" to finish, at which point Word will open, or I can click cancel (and a few other windows will pop up confirming the cancellation), at which point Word will open.

`.docx` files are **not** associated with Word (though I've tried to change that, several times!), this "configuration" process running every time I try to open a Word file from Explorer.

**What can I do to prevent this from happening?**

*The other Office suite programs (OneNote, Powerpoint, and Excel) are not affect by this problem, and open right away and without complaint.*

Here's a pic of the configuration message:

[image: "Configuration Progress"]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions problem. Try opening Word as administrator and let it do its configuring dialog until it completes. After it finishes up and Word is open you can close it and open it as a normal user to see if that fixed it.

Comment: Trying it out now.

Comment: Got an [error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OYQpR.png). Hit `Retry` and it came right back. What do you think? `Abort` or `Ignore`?

Comment: I would Ignore it. Font registration isn't exactly critical. Do you have the install disc?

Comment: No. I installed by download.

Comment: `Ignore` brings the error back. `Abort` started [rolling back changes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/afG11.png) ....now Word is open. Will try closing and reopening, and see if that helps. Nope, reopened and it goes right back to configuring again....

Comment: Sorry not familiar enough with 8.1 to continue. Sounds like you have corruption or a bad (un)install somewhere and need to do a system file check though.

Comment: +1 in any event, because this came close....I'll see if I can modify your solution to make it work.

Comment: I'll try calling Microsoft support tomorrow.